# Uploading image/videos in react.js

Tags: reactjs

i'm currently working on a project, and i need to upload images/videos in it, and i've done that before, except for the video...

I used react-file-base64 to upload the images, but i don't know if it supports videos as well.

So, my question is, what is the best package or dependecy to upload videos or images, whatever, does react-file-base64 support videos?

Comment: it will work as long as the video is base64